# btm mapping exception - Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element

Tags: xml, xslt, biztalk-mapper

I have `btm mapping file` I did `custom body mapping` like below but at the time of `transformation xslt gives below error` -

> Attribute and namespace nodes cannot be added to the parent element
>   after a text, comment, pi, or sub-element node has already been added

xslt mapping -

```
    <DemoParent>
 <IdRef>
                <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
                  <xsl:value-of select="header/msgHeader/Number/text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="identifier">
                  <xsl:value-of select="header/msgHeader/customerNumber/text()" />
                </xsl:attribute>

              </IdRef>
              <xsl:attribute name="name">
                <xsl:value-of select="$var:v12" />
              </xsl:attribute>
              <xsl:element name="TEST">
            <xsl:copy-of select="//*[local-name()='DEMO1' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='header' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='msgHeader' and namespace-uri()='']/*[local-name()='sale' and namespace-uri()='']/*" />
     </xsl:element>
            </DemoParent>
```

`<xsl:element name="TEST">` is added for custom mapping

Comment: Is that first `</IdRef>` supposed to be `<IdRef>`? What element do you think you're adding the `name` attribute to? If `DemoParent`, you need to move the `xsl:attribute` before the `IdRef`. (Or just add it directly like `<DemoParent name="{$var:v12}">`.)

Comment: There's something wrong with the code you've shown us, an IdRef end tag cannot immediately follow a DemoParent start tag.

Comment: Also, it seems pointless to create an `identifier` attribute and then create another `identifier` attribute effectively wiping out the value of the first one.

Comment: sorry typo was there updated properly

Comment: ` <xsl:element name="TEST">` is added for custom mapping

Answer (score 1):

The rule is that instructions that add attributes to an element must appear before/above instructions that add child nodes to the same element. (The error message talks in terms of order of execution, which is a polite fiction).

In your edited post we can see that for DemoParent, the instruction to create an IdRef child element appears above the xsl:attribute instruction that creates the name attribute; it needs to be moved so the attribute comes first.

Comment: thanks a lot , but i didnt understand term `instructions` here can you elaborate with change code snippet ? thanks

Comment: I'm a little puzzled by that comment because I don't see how you can learn to write XSLT code without ever reading what "instructions" are. How did you learn the language without coming across this term? All the XSLT elements that are evaluated to produce results are instructions: for example xsl:element, xsl:attribute, xsl:for-each, xsl:if; but not declarations like xsl:template and xsl:strip-space.

Comment: I'm just supporting one of the issue not having exact information about xslt lang :(
by the way thanks a lot for explanation this is helpful.